# Is there some way to apply filter based on cell color in libreoffice?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice-calc

The below answer doesn't work.

[LibreOffice Calc / OpenOffice Calc: How to filter rows based on their background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269321/libreoffice-calc-openoffice-calc-how-to-filter-rows-based-on-their-background)

I also tried putting sheet name and cell number in formula **=cell_backcolor(SHEET(), ROW(), 1)**, something like **=cell_backcolor(SHEET(12), ROW(A2), 1)**.
Any answers will be of great help, let me know if in above I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is related to incorrect use of the [**SHEET()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060109.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3153905) function - it is useless to expect that you get the sheet name in this way.

Fortunately, Villeroy (respect!) provided for the possibility of calling the function not by name, but by sheet number. Therefore, use a function call in the form of `=cell_backcolor(12, ROW(A2), 1)` where 12 is number of the twelfth sheet left-to-right

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the function cell_backcolor doesn't work for me. I'm new to libreOffice calc, Is there some other way to apply filter based on cell color in libreOffice. Any references will be of great help.

Comment: No, there is no built-in color filtering mechanism in this office. This is too complicated because there are many ways to change the color of a cell, from direct formatting to applying a style (including conditional). AFAIK the best that has been invented for today is the Villeroy macro. Perhaps, if you show your file or its simplified copy with the Villeroy macro enabled, we can understand why this function did not work for you.

Comment: No, my friend, we won't see this screenshot - it has remained on your computer, this image is not available on the Web